# get_object_or_404 Error page not found

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models

I'm trying to make a one to many relationship between phone numbers and messages. Whenever i select a number to show the messages sent to that number, i get 404 error.

**views.py**

```
def index(request):
    number = phoneNumber.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'number': number})

def detail(request, phonenumber):
    messages = get_list_or_404(Message, to=phonenumber)
    return render(request, 'messages.html', {'messages': messages})
```

**models.py**

```
class phoneNumber(models.Model):
    address = models.CharField(max_length=15)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.address

class Message(models.Model):
    to = models.ForeignKey(phoneNumber)
    sentfrom = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    content = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % (self.content)
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
        url(r'(?P<phonenumber>[0-9]+)', views.detail, name='detail'),
 ]
```

**index.html**

```
{% for num in number %}
    <ul>
        <li><a href="{% url 'detail' phonenumber=num.address %}">{{ num.address }}</a></li>
    </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

**messages.html**

```
{% for message in messages %}
    <p>{{ message }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: please share your urls.py

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to capture the phone number object before you can filter by it.

```
def detail(request, phonenumber):
    phonenumber_obj = get_object_or_404(phoneNumber, address=phonenumber)
    messages = get_list_or_404(Message, to=phonenumber_obj)
    return render(request, 'messages.html', {'messages': messages})
```